# jQuery: Function to remove all elements of multiple <select>?

Tags: jquery, button

I wanna make a function that erases everything inside of a multiple select using jQuery.
Also if it could remove some text from text fields it'd be good too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following to clear **all** multiple `select` elements:

```
$('select[multiple]').empty();
```

Replace `select` with a specific element if you do not want to clear all of them. The same applies to the following chunk of code. It can be used to clear all text fields:

```
$(':text').val('');
```

Comment: Perfect, what if I only want to clear two specific textfields (id1, and id2) how should it be?

Comment: @fgualda87: If you specified ID's on your elements, you can select them like this: `$('select#select-id[multiple]')` or `$('#text-id')`. You should take a look at jQuery's [Selector API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out by myself, but thanks though! It works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use .empty() to remove child elements from another element.
**Example:**  `$("#selectid1,#selectid2").empty()`

Without your HTML, it's hard to go into any more detail.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want to deselect everything and not remove from the DOM, try

```
$("select").val([]);
```

or something with a more specific selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Removing Options for Multiple Select Drop Down.

$('#FeatureId').multiselect("deselectAll", false).multiselect("refresh");